# Edit Contracts, Tax, and Banking details

Tags: app-store-connect

Can I edit or change/remove details in Contracts, Tax, and Banking ?

I have feel up the information in Contracts, Tax, and Banking section for the Bank details.Now contract's status is `Contracts In Effect` but I want to know that can I delete the bank info OR say disable, remove this contract from itunes.

I want to register my new bank account.

If so then when ?

Comment: The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly "you don't get". If you don't get a good answer, feel free to try editing in some details or links on what question you used and what step is failing or doesn't make sense. We love details here.

Comment: What specifically makes you think you can't change details of your iTunes connect account? There's got to be some back store you aren't sharing like you've already released apps tied to that account or is this more of a how does the web app or document submission process work?

Comment: @bmike : please see my edited question

Comment: @patrix: yes sorry for that...please check now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can edit your information in almost all instances without needing Apple's help.

Worst case, if you are locked out for more than a long weekend, open a ticket with Developer Support and you should have help to clear up your issues.